# Changing values in method that affect variables in main

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create code that validates a number. If the number is lower than 10 or higher than 20, the value of the number will be changed to 15.

Here is the code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        validateNumber(number);
        System.out.println(number);

    }

    public static int validateNumber(int number) {
        if (number < 10 || number > 20) {
            number = 15;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

The change in the method doesn't do anything in the main method.

Comment: It was a language design decision that passing a variable will never alter its value (one passes its value). `f(x)` will never set x to something else.

Comment: In Java variables of primitive data types (like int) are passed by value. Complex data types (everything that is a class) are passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

*easy-peasy, japanesey!*

```
number = validateNumber(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already return an Integer.
so just do:

```
number = validateNumber(number);
```

Thus it will override the `number` with the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this:

**1. Direct printing with function call :**

```
int number;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    number = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(validateNumber(number));
```

**2. Storage in a variable, then using it:**

```
int number;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    number = input.nextInt();
    
    int output = validateNumber(number);
    System.out.println(output);
```